# Cannot Create Directory error

Tags: c#, console-application, create-directory

I am trying to create a directory if it does not exist.  It correctly goes into the code to create the directory because it doesn't exist.  But then it gives me the following error:

DirectoryNotFoundException was unhandled

Could not find part of the path "\192.168.22.2\2009"

```
var fileYear = createdDate.Value.Year.ToString();
var fileMonth = createdDate.Value.Month.ToString();
var rootDir = @"\\192.168.22.2";

if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(rootDir,fileYear)))
     {
          // Create the Year folder
          Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(rootDir,fileYear));
     }
```

Comment: Missing the drive letter ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin there is no driver letter?  It is a network share.

Comment: @AustinSalonen no, just didn't put them in code tags.

Comment: Then shouldn't it begin with double slash ?

Comment: @mrlucmorin It did/does and now displays correctly in the original post.

Comment: You should have continued the discussion on your previous question, this is practically a duplicate.

Comment: It does not go correctly into the code because it doesn't exist, it goes in because it thinks \\192.168.22.2 doesn't exist. Do a Directory.Exists(rootDir) before it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson nice catch thank you.  Used so many File.Exists it was just second nature to throw it here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a share name after the `@"\\192.168.22.2"`.
Something like `@"\\192.168.22.2\MySharedFolder"`.

You cannot create a subfolder from that root dir

Comment: Hrm is it possible at all or just flat out impossible?  This folder must be at the root level for what I am working on to work properly.

Comment: No I think it is not possible. However you could map a drive letter to a shared folder and then use that letter as your root.

Comment: Yeah I don't think that will work as well, I'll just have to add the folders shares manually.  The current directory has 6 million files which causes our backup service to not work, so we had to break up that share into multiple root level shares by year and we think that'll get it to work again.

Comment: There's a built in admin share C$ (for the C drive :), so if you have admin access you can use that. This is really not a good idea though, as you have pretty much full control over the entire drive. I'd be looking at why it has to be on root.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it is because the backup service can really only handle about 3-4 million files.  And since we have used a single share (documentation) for all of our files this has grown to the point where the backup service can no longer back it up.  So we need to break up those files into multiple root folders broken down by year which will split up the files enough so the back up service can begin to backup these documents again.  But I can manually create them was just looking for a dynamic solution.